# How to unBind MusicService

Tags: android, service, bind

I am new in android, I'm working on a game app and I want to play Music in background, **the music has to be played in all activitys**. In addition, I am taking the songs **from the user's device** and present them in a ListView. The user chooses a song in the ListMusic Activity, then he go on to others Activity and **my purpose is that the music will continue in the background.**

I hope you understood the process, I added the JAVA also.

Now, I've got this error:

**Activity com.example.summerproject.FirstActivity has leaked    ServiceConnection com.example.summerproject.ListMusic$1@42116d20 that was  originally bound here**

From what I understood, the problem is that I am not UnBind the connection on onDestroy() of each activity. Someone know how to fix it? I want the music to continue over all the activitys so it might be a problem to unBind the Service each time.

**MusicService:**

```
   public class MusicService extends Service implements
   MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
   MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener
{
     private MediaPlayer player; //media player
     private ArrayList<Song> valuesList; //songs List
     private int songPosn;  //current position
     private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();
     
    public void onCreate()
     {
        
        super.onCreate(); 
        songPosn=0;
        player= new MediaPlayer();
        initMusicPlayer();
        
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
     }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        //בעת התחברות 
        return musicBind;
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent)
    {
      player.stop();
      player.release();
      return false;
    }
    
    public void initMusicPlayer() 
    {
          //set player properties
        player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
                player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
    
    public void playSong()
    {
         if(player != null) //אם נוצר כבר
            player.reset();
         
        Song songToPlay = valuesList.get(songPosn);
        long songId = songToPlay.getId();
        
        Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
          android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
          songId);
        
        try{
              player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
              Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
            }
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.prepareAsync();
          
    }
    public void setList(ArrayList<Song> theSongs){
          valuesList=theSongs;
        }
    
    public class MusicBinder extends Binder 
    {
          MusicService getService() 
          {
            return MusicService.this;
          }
    }
    
    public void setSong(int songIndex)
    {
          songPosn=songIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mp.start();        
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    


}
```

**ListActivity( the user chooses songs from here):**

```
 public class ListMusic extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
 {

  private static ArrayList<Song> valuesList;
private ListView list;
private MySongsAdapter songAdt;
private static MusicService MusicService;
private Intent playIntent;
private static boolean musicBound=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_music);
    
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.song_list);
    valuesList = new ArrayList<Song>();
    
    getSongList(); //update the valuesList
    
    songAdt = new MySongsAdapter(this, valuesList);
    list.setAdapter(songAdt);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}

//connect to the service

public static ServiceConnection musicConnection= new ServiceConnection()
{
 
  @Override
  public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) 
  {
    MusicBinder binder = (MusicBinder)service;
    //get service
    MusicService = binder.getService();
//  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music Service Is Not Null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //pass list
    MusicService.setList(valuesList);
    musicBound = true;
  }
 
  @Override
  public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    musicBound = false;
  }
};      
@Override
protected void onStart() 
{
    //
  super.onStart();
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  
    
  if(playIntent ==null)
  {
    playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
    bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    startService(playIntent);
  }
  
}

public void songPicked(View view, int position)
{
    //כאשר שיר נבחר
    MusicService.setSong(position);
    MusicService.playSong();
}

public void getSongList() 
{ 
    //אחזור רשימת השירים מהמכשיר
  ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
  Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
  Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
  
  long thisId;
  int titleColumn, idColumn, artistColumn;
  String thisTitle, thisArtist;
  
  if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst())
  {
      //get columns
      titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
        (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
      idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
        (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
      artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
        (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
      //add songs to list
      
      while (musicCursor.moveToNext())
      {
        thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
        thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
        thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
        valuesList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
      }

    }
  
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id)
{
     //באירוע של לחיצה על שיר
    songPicked(view, position);
    
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.music, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) 
{
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id= item.getItemId();
        switch(id)
        {
        case R.id.btnExit:
              stopService(playIntent);
              MusicService=null;
            finish();
              break;

        }
        return true;
    
}
```

**The connection to MainActivity:**

```
   playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
    bindService(playIntent, ListMusic.musicConnection,    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
       startService(playIntent);
```

Please, if anyone has an idea what is the problem, I would be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the music to continue over all the activitys so it might be a problem to unBind the Service each time.

This is only a problem because you do this

```
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent)
{
     player.stop();
     player.release();
     return false;
}
```

Now, every time something calls `unbindService()`, the music stops.  It is fine to call `unbindService()` in an activity's `onDestroy()` or `onPause()`, but then you should not stop the player in the `onUnbind()` method in the service.

You could give the service a public static method that you can call when you ned to stop the music instead:

```
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent)
{
     return false;
}

public static void stopPlayMusic()
{
     player.stop();
     player.release();
}
```

This way the music will keep on playing even if something unbinds from your service, while still having a way to stop the music from playing. To make this work, you have to make the `player` a static variable as well.

Comment: Or he can just read a tutorial on android services and have a service that runs in background and perfectly deals with binding and unbinding.

Comment: Oh, there's also one more thing you shouldn't avoid - dealing with AudioFocus in android. Again, there's a tutorial on that on developer.android.com.

Comment: Tim you forgot about both `started and bound service` pattern

Comment: I don't know if bound services are a good pick here, because he releases the mediaplayer everytime a context is unbound, that's why I suggested to not bind to it

Comment: yeah, but his wish is: `I want the music to continue over all the activitys` which is where started and bound service plays very well, also your statement `If the service was already running, great. If it wasn't, it will be created for you.` is not true in the default `bindService` call (with 0 flags)

Comment: @pskink true. Thanks for pointing that out. I often use BIND_AUTO_CREATE myself, so it kind of became natural to me

Comment: @pskink I think I confused myself a bit earlier, changed my answer now. Cheers